# WPF DataGrid, binding a SortedList containing <int,object>. How to show the object's members?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.0

I have just recently started using WPF (.NET 4.0), not using proper MVVM.

So I have a

```
SortedList<int, Person>
```

Person is a class having the public members: Name, Age, Address.

I would like to show only the Person and the Name, Age, Address fields in the DataGrid. How on earth do I do that? DataContext, ItemSource?
And it must be a SortedList because the order of the Persons is very important.

Please, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this method:
XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Value.Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Value.Age}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Value.Address}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
private void dataGridInit()
{
    SortedList<int, Person> list = new SortedList<int, Person>();
    list.Add(2, new Person() {Name = "James", Age = 30, Address = "some place" });
    list.Add(1, new Person() { Name = "Kitty", Age = 28, Address = "some place" });
    list.Add(3, new Person() { Name = "Deko", Age = 28, Address = "some place" });

    dataGrid.DataContext = list;
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Person Class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! A lot of suggestions, both you and dkozl knew the answer. It works!

Comment: You are welcome, i am happy that i am the 1st answer.please vote me. Thx!

Comment: It's not necessary to set the DataContext if you're setting the ItemsSource instead

Answer (score 1):

When you set `ItemsSource` to your `SortedList` each item will be of `KeyValuePair<int, Person>` type so you can get `Value` and this will have your `Name`, `Age` and `Address` property

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Value.Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Path=Value.Age}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Path=Value.Address}"/>
</DataGrid>
```