# WPF DataGrid, bound to a SortedList. How to get SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.0

Question relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697163/wpf-datagrid-binding-a-sortedlist-containing-int-object-how-to-show-the-obje).
How do I get the value from the row the user has selected? I can't seem to cast it into anything?

```
var value = dataGridPersons.SelectedItem;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
```

produces the following output (which I don't know how to cast):

```
[1, MyProject.Person]
```

How can I declare this into something useful? Generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained you in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697163/wpf-datagrid-binding-a-sortedlist-containing-int-object-how-to-show-the-obje/21697498#21697498) answer each item will be of `KeyValuePair<int, Person>` type so you need to cast `SelectedItem`

```
var selItem = (KeyValuePair<int, Person>)dataGridPersons.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Haha not my day today. I am missing the obvious because of so much new things in WPF. Thanks a bunch!